# how to make nsfw post with thumbanil

Tags: custom-field, loop, post-thumbnails, front-end

iam making a comic site like 9gag 
the front end upload page contains 
title 
upload image 
tags
NSFW [checkbox]
if every thing is normal 
the image become featured image of the post ,
i want the NSFW option to work ,
so if the uploader click the check box value (yes) will stored in costume filed called NFSWEG,
so in the loop page iam showing the thumbnail
by this code

```
<?php
   if(has_post_thumbnail())  {
    the_post_thumbnail(array(400,400, true),
    array("class" => "aligncenter featured_image")
      ); } ?>
```

iwant to replace the thumbanil with another image if the post have the value yes in the costume files 
your code worked perfectly 
now i want to implant it in this can you help me again 
 i tried really but the is always an error idont know why

thanks that was enough

Comment: What is NSFW? And, please, use proper lower/upper case in your text, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47/185667

Comment: I guess `Not Safe For Work` since we're talking about images here.

Answer (score 3):

[get_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) is your friend:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
    if ( 'yes' == get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'NFSWEG', true ) ) {
        echo '<img src="YOUR-IMAGE-HERE">';
    } else {
        the_post_thumbnail(
            array( 400, 400, true ), 
            array( "class" => "aligncenter featured_image" )
            ); 
    }
}
```